# If cell value changes, copy paste as value to same cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("bw1:bw1000")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Range(Target.Address).Copy
    Range(Target.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What is your question/problem

Comment: The problem is probably that this freezes excel, since it will infinitely proc itself.  You need to disable events before the copy/paste and then re-enable events afterwards

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` ===> Then Paste ====> `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: You want Worksheet_Calculate not change.

Comment: Really hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Cells in Column BW have formulas that get values from a different sheet. 
If I change a value on the linked sheet then a cell value changes in column BW. 
I want the changed value to be copy-pasted as value to the same cell that changed.

Comment: I hope my question is now clear and any support will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in the ThisWorkbook module (not a sheet module):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim ChangedCell As Range
    Dim OldVal As Variant
    Dim NewVal As Variant

    'Adjust the name of the worksheet to be the name of the actual sheet containing the formulas in column BW
    Set KeyCells = Me.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BW1:BW1000")

    If Sh.Name = KeyCells.Parent.Name Then
        For Each ChangedCell In KeyCells.Cells
            If ChangedCell.HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                NewVal = ChangedCell.Value
                Application.Undo
                OldVal = ChangedCell.Value
                Application.Undo
                If NewVal <> OldVal Then ChangedCell.Value = NewVal
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next ChangedCell
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Per comments from OP: "The macro is running for every change that I make in the file. Can I just limit the change to be triggered if I change value in H57 on sheet 'Mock'?"

To do so, delete the above code from the ThisWorkbook module and put the below code in the "Mock" sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim ChangedCell As Range
    Dim OldVal As Variant
    Dim NewVal As Variant

    If Target.Address = "$H$57" Then

        Set KeyCells = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main.Data").Range("BW1:BW1000")

        For Each ChangedCell In KeyCells.Cells
            If ChangedCell.HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                NewVal = ChangedCell.Value
                Application.Undo
                OldVal = ChangedCell.Value
                Application.Undo
                If NewVal <> OldVal Then ChangedCell.Value = NewVal
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next ChangedCell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The cell that changed still has the formula. I want the changed value to be pasted as a value and remove the formula with something like .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: @AJ_FELIX I have tested it and can confirm that it will remove the formula and only have the value.  If you are getting different results, make sure the sheet name and cell range are correct in the KeyCells assignment.

Comment: @AJ_FELIX Also make sure the code is in the ThisWorkbook code module.

Comment: My sheet name is Main.Data and I just tried to change the value of another cell by changing the source / linked cell and result is still the same.

Comment: @AJ_FELIX Did you edit the provided code so that instead of "Sheet1" it says "Main.Data" ?

Comment: By the way I removed the code I pasted above from the sheet module. Should I let it remain there?

Comment: @AJ_FELIX Deleting it is good, you don't want the original code there.

Comment: Yes. 
 
@AJ_FELIX Did you edit the provided code so that instead of "Sheet1" it says "Main.Data" ? – tigeravatar 18 secs ago

Comment: @AJ_FELIX If it's not working for you, then there is something else going on, and to correct it I would need to actually view the workbook, which is beyond the scope of this forum.  I can verify that the provided code has been tested and works successfully.  Good luck, and I hope you can adapt the solution to resolve your issue.

Comment: OK my mistake. I just closed the file and reopened it and now its working but only too well. The macro is running for every change that I make in the file. Can I just limit the change to be triggered if I change value in H57 on sheet 'Mock'?